# Asteroids between Mars and Jupiter

Tags: solar-system, asteroids, jupiter, mars

Is the cluster of asteroids between Mars and Jupiter two dimensional as seen in every model of solar system shown in books or television? Or is it three dimensional as i think it should be?

Comment: I also discuss this in my answer to [How do spacecraft navigate through the Asteroid belt to avoid collision?](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/3203/49) on [space.se], if you're interested. For statistical purposes, it would probably be easiest defined as a toroid, not a disc. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Many models shown in books or television show a very populated asteroid belt but in fact the belt is mostly empty.

To answer your question, the inclination of the asteroids vary a lot going from 0° to 40° although most off them are in between 0° and 30°; See [The orbital element distributions of real and modelled asteroids](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v460/n7253/fig_tab/nature08094_F1.html). So yes it would be 3 dimensional.